# How to identify the radio button in selenium, if id and name have the same value

Tags: selenium-webdriver, radio-button

I have tried to make Selenium click a radio button. Selenium is unable to select any of the radio buttons because `id` and `name` for the radio buttons are the same.

I am adding the `html` code below:

```
<label for="gender">Gender</label>
<input id="gender " name="gender" value="M" type="radio"/>
  Male    
<input id="gender " name="gender" value="F" type="radio"/>
  Female
<label class="error" for="gender"/>
```

Comment: Please share the html for radio buttons you are trying to click.

Comment: @jainishkapadia, somehow it is not visible to me. I tried reloading, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code.

If you want to click on `Male` then use below code using `xpath` locator..

```
WebElement radio_male = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='M']"));
radio_male.click();
```

> OR

If you want to click `Female` radio button then use below code using `xpath` locator.

```
WebElement radio_female = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='F']"));
radio_female.click();
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `value` attribute of `<input>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Boolean btnSelected = odriver.findElement(By.id("enrollUserOptionsDiv")).isSelected();
                    if(btnSelected = true){
                        if(odriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value=\"No\"]")).isSelected())
                        {
                            System.out.println( odriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value=\"No\"]")).isSelected());
                            odriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value=\"Yes\"]")).click();} //fails at this line
```

Comment: I replaced last line with and it worked :List oRadioButton = odriver. findElements(By.id("newUserId"));
((WebElement) oRadioButton.get(0)).click();